# Is it possible to simplify this htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to simplify this htaccess file? (it is for a german website about mathematics)
Here comes the content of the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/quadrat-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/rechteck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$ testversion/formeln/index.php?id=2 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/raute-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=3 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/deltoid-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=4 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/parallelogramm-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=5 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/trapez-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=6 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/sehnenviereck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=7 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/gleichseitiges-dreieck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=8 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/gleichschenkliges-dreieck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=9 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/rechtwinkliges-dreieck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=10 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/allgemeines-dreieck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=11 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/kreis-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=12 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/kreisring-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=13 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/kreissektor-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=14 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/ellipse-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=15 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/regelmäßiges-sechseck-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=16 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/würfel-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=17 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/quader-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=18 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/tetraeder-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=19 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/oktaeder-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=20 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/dodekaeder-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=21 [PT]
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/ikosaeder-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=22 [PT]
```

Thank you in advance for your tips and suggestions!

Comment: In terms of htaccess magic the answer would be no. What you could do is use a proper (php) router. The question would be: do you really need to?

Comment: Can you check my answer if it suits?

Comment: Are the links on the left legacy ones, being remapped to a new system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I can think of is, using a router. If at all, any requests come to:

```
testversion/formeln/(.*)-formeln-und-eigenschaften
```

We can put them to another file. So your `.htaccess` will become like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/(.*)-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/redirect.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

And using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) get the values changed in the `redirect.php`:

```
<?php
    $listFiles = array(
        "",
        "quadrat",
        "rechteck",
        "raute",
        "deltoid",
        "parallelogramm",
        "trapez",
        "sehnenviereck",
        "gleichseitiges-dreieck",
        "gleichschenkliges-dreieck",
        "rechtwinkliges-dreieck",
        "allgemeines-dreieck",
        "kreis",
        "kreisring",
        "kreissektor",
        "ellipse",
        "regelmäßiges-sechseck",
        "würfel",
        "quader",
        "tetraeder",
        "oktaeder",
        "dodekaeder",
        "ikosaeder"
    );
    header("Location: index.php?id=" + array_search($_GET["id"], $listFiles))
?>
```

Comment: This hybrid version is far less explicit than the original.

Comment: @Progrock I don't understand?

Comment: You have introduced a hard dependency on a rewrite rule.  Your ids aren't immediately obvious either.  I'd either keep the original or replace completely with a Php version.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the GET parameter as a second identifier:

instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/quadrat-formeln-und-eigenschaften$  testversion/formeln/index.php?id=1 [PT]
...
...
```

you should do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^testversion/formeln/([a-z-]{1,})$  testversion/formeln/index.php?get_parameter=$1 [PT]
```

"quadrat-formeln-und-eigenschaften" should be equal to the the value of `get_parameter` WHERE `id`=1. So add the field to your table and give unique values for each row.

Comment: welcome, please try this way. otherwise your htaccess will grow and grow. do not take praveen's solution, which is just another workaround.